# Setting NA in a matrix using another logical matrix

Tags: r, indexing, na

*I just saw what seemed like a perfectly good question that was deleted and since like the original questioner I couldn't find a duplicate, I'm posting again.*

Assume that I have a simple matrix ("m"), which I want to index with another logical matrix ("i"), keeping the original matrix structure intact. Something like this:

```
# original matrix
m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3, ncol = 4)

# logical matrix
i <- matrix(c(rep(FALSE, 6), rep(TRUE, 6)), nrow = 3, ncol = 4)

m
i

# Desired output:
matrix(c(rep(NA,6), m[i]), nrow(m), ncol(m))
# however this seems bad programming...
```

Using `m[i]` returns a vector and not a matrix. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I took the intent to assign NA from the specified result and from the fact that both his solution and my alternate gave the same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original poster added a comment saying he'd figured out a solution, then almost immediately deleted it:

```
 m[ !i ] <- NA
```

I had started an answer that offered a slightly different solution using the `is.na<-` function:

```
 is.na(m) <- !i
```

Both solutions seem to be reasonable R code that rely upon logical indexing. (The `i` matrix structure is not actually relied upon. A vector of the proper length and entries would also have preserved the matrix structure of `m`.)

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions provide above works and are fine. Here is another solution to produce a new matrix, without modifying the previous one. Make sure that your matrix of logical values are well store as logical, and not as character.

```
vm <- as.vector(m)
vi <- as.vector(i)
new_v <- ifelse(vi, vm, NA)
new_mat <- matrix(new_v, nrow = nrow(m), ncol=ncol(m))
```

Comment: I'm guessing that it would have been simpler and faster to simply create a copy that could then be modified. The `ifelse` would have needed to create 3 object of the same length as the original matrix and then do an assignment into a fourth one.

Comment: Yes of course. There is always different ways to do. I just wanted to give another example of how solve this problem, step by step. (which is sometimes easier to understand for beginners).